# Ruby on Rails... Oauth? Getting Started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

First, let me begin by telling you I am new to web development.

I come here from a C and C++ Background. Web Development I am being thrown into the deep end with at the moment, and I am a little lost, so, apologies if some of my questions are a little stupid. I have dabbled with ASP.net, but I understand it is different to Ruby on Rails.

I have my rails environment setup, and I am able to see the initial welcome to rails page when I load it in the browser. Thats fine... But, the first thing I need this page to do is accept Oauth login functionality, via twitter. I can't use the twitter gem though, this has to be done using only the OAuth Gem.

I have through a bunch of tutorials, and all of them say I need to start with creating an instance of a consumer. By passing a configuration hash...

Where do I write the code for that though? on the default page of my application? or in a config file or something?

I am completely unfamiliar with the layout of anything in ruby on rails right now. I will go back and learn in greater detail, but for now I just need to get this up and running as quick as I can.

Comment: I've done something like this in a recent project, it's private on Github though. If you let me know your Github username I'll invite you into the repo and you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [#235 OmniAuth Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) or the [OmniAuth](http://www.omniauth.org) gem directly.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after. I am fully familiar with coding etc, I just wasn't sure how ruby on rails hangs together.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend against "just getting something up and running" without understanding at least some of Rails' architecture and conventions. Learn these, and Rails will do a lot for you.

I haven't used OmniAuth yet, but I highly recommend [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) - if you have a user backed application. Install it as described in the link.

Then you can just put this line of code

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

in your application controller, and it will redirect to the login page which was generated by devise.

In case you don't need this user oriented approach and just want to generally protect your app from being looked at without a password, this might do the trick:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # before_filter :authenticate

  protect_from_forgery

  protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "put username here" && password == "put password here"
    end
  end
end
```

This will trigger a basic http password request, like the one you may know from htaccess, and compare the user's input against what you put in the vars `username` and `password` above.